# フォルダにあるJSONファイルのデータをjQueryですべて読み込むには？

Tags: jquery

例えば、sampleフォルダにいくつかのjsonデータがあるとして、それを全て読み込みたい場合はどう記述すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: すべてのJSONファイルの名前はリストとして持っていますか？それとも何のJSONファイルがあるかわからない状態での取得ですか？

Comment: jQueryが出てくるくらいなので、実行環境はウェブブラウザでよろしいでしょうか?

Comment: >>すべてのJSONファイルの名前はリストとして持っていますか？それとも何のJSONファイルがあるかわからない状態での取得ですか？ 
答えになっているか分からないですが、、、sample1.json,sample2.jsonといった感じです。

Comment: >>実行環境はウェブブラウザでよろしいでしょうか?
はい、あっています。

Comment: ファイル名は連番ですか? 連番の最大値はわかりますか? 欠番はありますか? サーバ側で何らかのプログラムを走らせることはできますか?

Answer (score 2):

読み込むだけであれば次のようにするのはどうでしょうか。

```js
// ここのファイル名が必要なだけ増えていく
const filenames = [
  "sample/data.json",
  "sample/data2.json"
];

filenames.forEach(function (filename) {
  $.getJSON(filename, function (data) {
    console.log(filename, data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

以前同じ目的で調べたことがあり、標準では用意されていないと知り、
実装したことがあります。

手元にあったそのコード（TypeScript）をJavaScriptに書き直しました。
いま環境がないので動作は未確認です。（上手く動いたら良いのですが）

アプローチとしては
まずディレクトリ内に含まれる全ファイルを列挙した後で、拡張子で絞る感じです。

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const enumFilePaths = (dirPath, extension) => {
    const filePaths = [];

    const founds = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
    founds.each((found) => {
        const subPath = path.resolve(dirPath, found);
        const stat = fs.statSync(subPath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            filePaths.push(subPath);
        }
    });

    const filtered = filePaths.filter((filePath) => {
        const ext = path.extname(filePath).toLowerCase().replace('.', '');
        return ext === extension;
    });

    return filtered;
};

const jsonFilePaths = enumFilePaths('./sample', 'json');
```

この `jsonFilePaths` をループで回して、`$.getJSON()` されると良いです。

少し改造すると、探す拡張子を2つ以上に増やしたり、
サブディレクトリ内も探すようにもできます。
（元々その機能もありましたが、あなたの要件とは異なるのでペーストの際に省略しました）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！助かります。

Comment: げげ、他のコメントで「実行環境はウェブブラウザ」と書かれていますね。それだとこのコードは動作しません。`fs.readdirSync()` のような、ローカルPC内のファイルを参照することは、ブラウザからはセキュリティ上できないのです。

Comment: 遅くなりました。回答ありがとうございます。知識不足な点があり、もう少し調べてみます。